# can't get data from database on http.get call

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

hey guys i have problem that i'm not sure what's wrong with it, i'm trying to get data from the database on http call and return it to front end.this is what i have so far

```
app.get('/contentHandler/post/frontPage', contentHandler.displayMainPage);
```

**displayMainPage**

```
 this.displayMainPage = function(req, res, next) {
        "use strict";
        posts.getPosts(10, function(err, result) { //the 10 is limit to 10 post
            "use strict";
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.send(200,result); // send it to front end 
        });
    }
```

**getPosts**

```
  this.getPosts = function(num, callback) {
        "use strict";
        posts.find().sort('date', -1).limit(num).toArray(function(err, items) {
            "use strict";

            if (err) return callback(err, null);

            console.log("Found " + items.length + " posts");

            callback(err, items);
        });


    }
```

**front end(angular js controller)**

```
function IndexCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/contentHandler/post/frontPage').
      success(function(data) {
        alert(data); // alert nothing/blank 
      }).error(function(err) {

      });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma(,) after the **$http** **,** . Because single comma helps to does not allow to the next process :p lol

try this code instead of your code

```
function IndexCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/contentHandler/post/frontPage').
      success(function(data) {
        alert(data); // alert nothing/blank 
      }).error(function(err) {

      });


}
```

Comment: even i delete the comma i still get the same result, which is nothing

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma (,) after $http and then try your code.

Comment: even i delete the comma i still get the same result, which is nothing